# how to compare the two date

Tags: php, date

I have a MySQL database with a PHP front end.  In my records I have a posted date and an expire date directly accessed from the database.  What I need to do is check and see if any records expire date matches posted date.

Something like:

```
<?php $posted_date= $row_Recordset1['date_posted']; ?>
<?php $exp_date= $row_Recordset1['expire_date']; ?>      

<?php if ($posted_date("Y-m-d") >= $exp_date("Y-m-d")) {
    //statement
<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: $row_Recordset1 sounds like a database result. Which rdbms is it? What's the format of the date values? (`echo  $row_Recordset1['date_posted'];`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$posted_date= $row_Recordset1['date_posted'];
$exp_date= $row_Recordset1['expire_date'];      

if (strtotime($posted_date) >= strtotime($exp_date)) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

This would work assuming that dates from the DB are the standard formated date strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn them into [Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime), assuming they start out as a string, and then they'll just be integers, which you can compare. Another option would be to use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) objects, which can be compared using comparison operators. If your date is represented as a format `strtotime` understands, you can do `$dt=new DateTime($row_Recordset1['expire_date']);`