# How to Compare Dates in php?

Tags: php

i need code to compare date in php

1. Input date should be a valid date
2. input date should not be less than the current date.
3. i need to give time zones EST,PST,etc..
4. We need to make the time to GMT and compare with Current Time.

can anyone help on this.
Thanks
Ramakrishnan.p

Comment: This has been much discussed already: **[how to compare the two date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496483/how-to-compare-the-two-date)** **[Compare date in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347082/compare-date-in-php)** **[PHP - Compare Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/php-compare-date)** **[PHP How to compare date and date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355075/php-how-to-compare-date-and-date)** **[Shortest way to compare 2 dates in dd/mm/yyyy format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729680/shortest-way-to-compare-2-dates-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format)** **[And

Comment: Have you had a look through the time functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php), what have you done with them, is there any particular problem you're having?

Answer (score 4):

This is a late answer. since there is no exact answer to the question here, I'm providing this solution here.

You can do it in this way

```
$date1 = strtotime("2007-02-20"); // your input
$date2 = strtotime("today"); //today
if($date1 < $date2) {
    echo " input date is in the past";
}
```

strtotime converts the string in to the unix timestamp integer.

Comment: will it compare date if there is a month difference eg $date1="2016-11-01" and  $date2="2016-12-01" ?

Comment: Basically it compares 2 dates so it should not be a problem if there is a month difference

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [maketime()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function. Then compare the resulting UNIX timestamps.

Comment: New link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php or just google php mktime ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Zend Framework's Date: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.overview.html You just need the Date.php file and the Date/Locale folders from the framework to use it.