# Using less than calculation in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php

I have three dates to compare:

```
$pDate = date("d/m/Y G:i A");
$lDate = new DateTime('last wednesday G:i A');
$cDate = new DateTime('next tuesday G:i A');
```

If *$pDate* is in between *$lDate* and *$cDate* then mysql table field is updated yes

i.e. the 9th is in between the 8th and 14th

If *$pDate* is less than equal to *$lDate* then MySQL table field is updated no

*$pDate* cannot be more than *$cDate*

How would I write a elseif statement for the above? i.e.

```
elseif ( .... ) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($lDate < $pDate && $cDate > $pDate) {
 // do table insert or update here
} else {
 // date is not in desired range.
}
```

php date compares like a number.

Heres a post you should look at.
[How to Compare Dates in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902360/how-to-compare-dates-in-php)

Comment: thanks! so it works even if my date is in the UK format dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: I am not sure on that, I am reading the other post as I haven't tried that before. ( my guess is yes )

Answer (score 0):

you can try `IF ELSE` condition in the `MySQL` query.
try this to solve your problem, let me know if you dont.