# how to compare dates

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Compare Dates in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902360/how-to-compare-dates-in-php)

I have these two dates

1305004066

1305007443

I want to compare which one is later on than other. How can I do that

Comment: In your case however, it's just a question of a `>` comparison or `max()` http://php.net/max

Answer (score 3):

If it's UNIX timestamps (seconds since 1970-01-01), the largest one is the latest:

```
$latest = max($time1, $time2);
```