# Array doesn't sort by time

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$arr1 = array("time"=>'2011 10-06 10:20:10', "val"=>20);
$arr2 = array("time"=>'2011 11-06 10:20:10', "val"=>20);
$arr3 = array("time"=>'2011 05-06 10:20:10', "val"=>20);
$arr4 = array("time"=>'2011 07-06 10:20:10', "val"=>20);
$arr5 = array("time"=>'2011 09-06 10:20:10', "val"=>20);


$arrGroup[1] = array($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4, $arr5); //Add key here


foreach ($arrGroup as $key => $row) {

    foreach($row as $rKey=> $rVal){

        $time[$rKey]  = $rVal['time'];

        $val[$rKey] = $rVal['val'];
    }

}
```

I would like to sort this array by its 'time'. However, the above code doesn't sort the array.

Comment: You need to use `strtotime()` to convert to a timestamp, then you can easily use one of the `sort()` family of functions.

Comment: There are no times in that array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Compare Dates in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902360/how-to-compare-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Convert the time to timestamp value and then use sort method to sort by date.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be simpler to use the timestamp as the index to the outer array if you want to maintain the data structure for your inner array

```
$arrGroup[1] = array(
    '1234567890' => $arr1, 
    '1234567891' => $arr2, 
    '1234567892' => $arr3,
    '1234567893' => $arr4, 
    '1234567894' => $arr5
); 

asort($arrGroup[1]);
```